# Use Ubuntu laptop as a Wi-Fi repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, ubuntu-14.04

Well I have two questions actually...

The first one is can I use my Ubuntu laptop to extend the Wi-Fi network to which my laptop is connected same in Windows through [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me)?

The second one is that the Wi-Fi through which I connect to Internet uses Squid-proxy authentication. I want to broadcast a authenticated Wi-Fi, if possible, to use it with my Windows phone.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't post an answer but check out this Archwiki page : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/324785

Comment: @KumarPratyaksh Can you please test the answers? I don't have access to spare laptop at the moment.

Comment: Found a solution for the second question...sorry for being absent so late...u just have to cascade proxies for that...install squid3 on your system and configure it to use with your wifi ip, chain it with the parent proxy u want to authenticate....now u just have to put your systems ip in the proxy settings on the phone...most apps will work with this

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 14.04, there is the option right in the connect menu. Click on the Wi-Fi icon at the top-right corner of your screen and then click on the `Create new Wi-Fi network`. It opens the dialog box, where you can give it the name, protection method and password. So there is no need to install any other package like Connectify.

And as for the second question, it will be more complicated. If it doesn't work automatically, then you should edit some Wi-Fi settings through `dconf-editor`. Better to ask experienced users at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Hope it helps.

Comment: It works also great on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

You can do that from the terminal. But first your laptop's network card must support AP (access point). Check out [this question on ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot) how to do that. Also you will find there how to set it up. But in case you want to share the connection from the same card you are connected with the other windows laptop, that can be done only with some cards only. Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap/324785#324785) (as mentioned on one of the comments above too).
Now, if that doesn't work, I would recommend another way...
Try using the ubuntu laptop to share the internet, and the windows one as a "repeater". Some people say it works (as I never tried myself), using  [this tool from microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/994abd5f-53d1-4dba-a9d8-8ba1dcccead7/).
If that doesn't work too, than the only way it to use two different wireless cards on the ubuntu laptop, or to connect both laptops with a LAN cable (sharing the internet through the cable), and with the ubuntu laptop share the connection via wireless. 
Now for the second question... I'm not sure if I got it right, but is that proxy configured in the router? If so, [here is some help](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringBrowsers) on how to configure browsers on Squid. And if you want to configure a wireless connection to use proxy from your windows phone, check [this tutorial](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-add-proxy-server-wireless-connection-windows-phone-8).
Now if you want to create a proxy server based on Squid, so that windows phone can connect to, I'm not quite sure how you can do that on ubuntu, but as for windows is pretty similar as a normal proxy server. Check [this tutorial](http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/how-to-set-up-a-proxy-server-704981) for that.

P.S.
In case I was off point somewhere or I didn't understood the question properly, please let me know, so maybe I can help you farther.